# How to add a loading view for apple watch?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I want to display a loading view (the one provided by apple) once a WKInterfaceButton is pressed:

[image: 1]

I need this because after the WKInterfacebutton is pressed, I'm calling the main iPhone app to do some service calls which will take some time to return a response.

```
    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(watchMessage, reply: { (reply:[NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

Comment: Fyi, loading screens will be considered as bad practice. Apple HIG prefers you to put placeholder data rather than loading screen, if possible. In the watch HIG, they wrote: "If the interaction time of iPhone apps is measured in minutes, then for the apple watch, it's in seconds". You should avoid it fyi.

Comment: Hi @KelvinLau, why is it considered as a bad practice? Apple is also using loading screen for transition between screens. I couldn't find a way to trigger that loading screen. If the worst comes to the worst, I'll have to use own animation.

Comment: What's a "placeholder data" btw? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: A [splash screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen) is an example of placeholder data.

Comment: @user1872384 I think a better technique to use is to load your interface with cached data, and updating it when the results come in. Perhaps use the tiny activity spinner to show that data is being loaded. (not the big full screen one) 

The point is, nobody wants to see a spinner on their device for long. There are better practices than to use Apple's full screen spinner. In fact, I don't believe you'll ever see that spinner we see in the simulator when you actually use the actual watch. The simulator is known to be slow compared to the actual devices.

Comment: Thx for the tips Kelvin! Typically, the loading will only take ~1.5seconds on my simulator. however sometimes user will be using Edge/3G connection on their phone which will slow down the loading process. I have no choice but to use the loading animation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used very simple progress using WKInterfaceLabel,

Create properties and outlets,

```
@IBOutlet private var loadingLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
private var loadingTimer = Timer()
private var progressTracker = 1
```

Implementation,

```
func startProgressIndicator() {
    // Reset progress and timer.
    progressTracker = 1
    loadingTimer.invalidate()

    // Schedule timer.
    loadingTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    loadingLabel.setHidden(false)
}

@objc
private func updateProgress() {
    switch progressTracker {
    case 1:
        lastUpdateLabel.setText("Loading..")
        progressTracker = 2
    case 2:
        lastUpdateLabel.setText("Loading...")
        progressTracker = 3
    case 3:
        lastUpdateLabel.setText("Loading.")
        progressTracker = 1
    default:
        break
    }
}

func stopProgressIndicator() {
    loadingTimer.invalidate()
    lastUpdateLabel.setHidden(true)
}
```

Use these functions to show and hide,

```
startProgressIndicator()
stopProgressIndicator()
```

Comment: The question is specifically tagged with `swift`. Your code is in Objective-C. I'm sure that OP would love to spend hours of his time learning a new language just to understand your answer, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Implementation is correct and there is no any special or third party API are  used here So same code can be easily written to swift.

Comment: You're missing the point. The OP might not *know* Objective-C.

Comment: Question is also tagged with 'watchkit'. It can also be helpful to other SO users who is looking for a solution for loading view in watchkit.

Comment: There should be no reason for downvote here. If anyone knows the swift version then he would add his answer with that.

Comment: You do understand the concept of answering a question, right? OP wants a Swift solution. You could post all the data in the world about WatchKit, but it wouldn't make it *relevant* to the question.

Comment: This solution should help point the OP in the right direction, and at least this responder was good enough to provide SOME code- (which the people complaining didn't!). Also the OPs question didn't SAY Swift (although it did show a line of code and use a Swift tag)

Comment: Hi @DH14-SL, thank you for providing such a comprehensive answer... I'm able to write in both obj-c and swift... Don't have any issue reading the code. I've decided to use an image to do the loading to reduce the effort to code.